# Display Description Category for OPencart 2.0

Tags: opencart2.x

I used mod bycategory to display products on homepage
Now, im' want display **description category**(don't product) (on homepage)
Code catalog/controller/module/bycategory.php

```
 <?php
    class ControllerModuleBycategory extends Controller {
        public function index($setting) {
            $this->load->language('module/bycategory');

            $data['heading_title'] = $setting['name'];

            $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');

            $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
            $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
            $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $this->load->model('tool/image');

            $data['products'] = array();

            $filter_data = array(
                'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'start' => 0,
                'limit' => $setting['limit'],
                'filter_category_id'=>$setting['category']
            );

            $data['type'] =  $setting['type'];

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            if ($results) {
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    if ($result['image']) {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                    } else {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $setting['width'], $setting['height']);
                    }

                    if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    } else {
                        $price = false;
                    }

                    if ((float)$result['special']) {
                        $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    } else {
                        $special = false;
                    }

                    if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                        $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
                    } else {
                        $tax = false;
                    }

                    if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                        $rating = $result['rating'];
                    } else {
                        $rating = false;
                    }

                    $data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                        'thumb'       => $image,
                        'name'        => $result['name'],
                        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                        'price'       => $price,
                        'special'     => $special,
                        'tax'         => $tax,
                        'rating'      => $rating,
                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
                    );
                }

                if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/bycategory.tpl')) {
                    return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/bycategory.tpl', $data);
                } else {
                    return $this->load->view('default/template/module/bycategory.tpl', $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And code catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/bycategory.tpl

```
  <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
  <?php
    if($type=="vertical"){
      ?>
         <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <?php
    }else{
      ?>
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <?php
    }
  ?> 
   <div class="product-thumb transition">
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
        <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
        <div class="rating">
          <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
        <p class="price">
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
          <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
        </p>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

How to display **[![description for category][1]][1]** (by category in homepage)?
Help me!
Link demo http://duhocaaumy.com/demo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

Add below code in **catalog/controller/module/bycategory.php**

```
$category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($setting['category']);
$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Go to **catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/bycategory.tpl**

Add below code where you want to display category description

```
<?php echo $description; ?>
```